# How "this" operator works in java?

Tags: java

Iam beginner to java. Can u tell me how "**this**" operator passes value to instance variable in a method.

example:

```
public class Cricketer {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how it will process.can any explain it clearly.

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the current object.  So `this.name` means the field `name` in the current object.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is silently passed by the compiler as a hidden parameter that you can use to reference the current object.  Non-static methods automatically get `this` passed to them.

Answer (score 0):

your method setName() is not static, so it means you need an instance of Cricketer to be called

```
Cricketer c = new Cricketer();
c.setName("xyz");
```

so your method setName() could be understood as something like

```
c.name = "xyz";
```

c is "this".

Answer (score 0):

If you call an instance method (not a static method) in `Cricketer`, you need to give it an object:

```
Cricketer x = new Cricketer(...);

x.someMethod();
```

Inside the body of `someMethod`, you can use `this` to mean "the object that you're calling the method on", which in this case is `x`.

Similarly, inside the body of a *constructor*, `this` will mean "the object that we just created".

So here, inside `setName`, `this.name` means "the `name` member of the object that we called `setName` on".  Usually, inside an object's methods, you can just say `name` instead of `this.name`; the problem here is that the code is using `name` for a different meaning, i.e. the string you're passing to `setName`, and that meaning has priority inside the body of `setName`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that normally you don't need to use this to access a field in the current object, but in the above code there is also a parameter called `name` which hides the unqualified use of `name` to access the field in the object. Using `this.name` allows the field to be accessed in spite of the parameter "hiding" it.